# How to remain technical/objective without advertising my open source library too much

Tags: discussion, advertising, open-source

Hm, there are a lot of interesting links in the related questions to my own question. I'll still ask it though:

I love stackoverflow for the high-quality feedback I get. I use it essentially for my job in every-day work, as well as for important design decisions for my Java open source library [jOOQ](http://jooq.sourceforge.net). While my questions are of technical nature and interesting to the broad public, I admit that I don't dislike the fact that I can subtly advertise jOOQ a little, when putting my question in the proper context. Now here's my meta-question:

How much advertising is OK in my questions, given the fact that I do not have any financial interests, but that I think I can give something to the community, while working on an interesting, fun, "instructional" project?

Should I tag my questions about the inner workings of jooq (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439229/mapping-between-oracle-packages-and-java-packages)) with the `jooq` tag, or should that tag be reserved to questions about using `jooq` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474365/jooq-and-spring)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I changed my mind after reading through your questions a few times: while self-promotion is surely to be dealt with carefully in general, I find it hard to be too critical of the question you link to.)

Reference:

- [Limit to self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers)
- [How do I mention my own products in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I exactly felt that way... not quite right, so I was interested in the "official" position of the stackexchange folks and the community.

Comment: @Lukas you're welcome. On second thought, I felt my response was a bit too strong:  The question you link to doesn't feel spammy to me at all, even though you clearly point to it. But the general point surely stands, it's good not to overdo self-promotion no matter whether it's an Open Source or commercial project.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I want to have a good balance of linking to it where applicable (e.g. to understand the general context) or just asking the actual question itself, if it's about a simple thing that doesn't need mentioning my product...

Answer (score 4):

Please continue to do this carefully and sparingly.  I don't see any fault with the question you linked to because you had a legitimate question and the background information on what you're trying to do is helpful.  However, if people see you promoting your own project too often they'll flag it as spam no matter what we decide here.  If you start to draw too many flags you'll start to lose reputation for it.

Answer (score 1):

If the primary intent of your "Answer" is obviously to answer the question then advertise as you see fit. When you contribute little to the question and shamelessly plug your wares, that's spam even if you include an answer on technicality.