# Deleted answers (considered as advertisement). Can I submit the answer again with a disclaimer?

Tags: discussion

I understand that Stack Overflow is not a place for advertising, but what if I have an answer that suggests a potential solution for the problem and includes a link to the product (both open source and commercial) developed by me or the company I work for? Is it enough if I state that it's "my" or "our" product? Or should I write a disclaimer like "I'm a developer" or "I work for [the company]"? I'm not sure why my answers are removed and can I submit a similar answer with a disclaimer?

Comment: dupe-ish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers

Comment: From the [FAQ#promotion]: "Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Answer (score 14):

If:

1. The link(s) are not the only thing in your answer, i.e. it has free-standing content
2. It's not the only type of answers you give
3. It's topical and relevant to the question
4. Your association with that link is obvious without needing to actually click the link

given all of these then I'd say it's reasonable to post in general, since it adds value as an answer.

**However**, if you have an old post that was deleted then editing that and flagging once the post has been improved and those have been met is a much better strategy. Make sure the flag clearly requests undeletion, explaining your changes. This would be appropriate and obvious than simply re-posting.

(Duplications of deleted posts look like crude attempts at evading deletion when reviewing)

Comment: Definitely edit and undelete or flag for undeletion.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say no, because we honestly don't need your spam, thanks.

BRB, closing most of the questions you answered as spam-bait.

Comment: I understand that nobody likes spam and I'm not going to post some irrelevant answers. I've seen some answers that contain a link to the (paid) product and a disclaimer "I'm a developer of this product", that's why I'm asking this question. But I've got your idea, thanks.

Comment: If the answers were relevant (and actually answered the questions in  a constructive way, despite linking to one specific product), would they still be considered spam?

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind advertisements at all --provided the product solves the problem. After all, that is the way we discover new libraries and programs. If you can prove that your product works (and why it works or even better how it works), I don't see a reason why you shouldn't promote it.

Personally, I will up vote it as long as your post shows that your product will solve the problem and that there is no cheaper (including cost to build it in house) alternative.

This, hence, excludes promotions done for solely the sake of promotion and not for answering the root problem and most people (including me) will down vote it.

Regardless of these cases, deletions done for evading a review are just a cheap attempt to advertise --you got to pay for the adverts don't you? So why not pay by some negative votes?