# What can I do when my posts have mis-identified as spam?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleted answers (considered as advertisement). Can I submit the answer again with a disclaimer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121522/deleted-answers-considered-as-advertisement-can-i-submit-the-answer-again-wit)

A couple of days ago, I posted a series of similar answers to a group of similar questions (which were basically asking "Is it possible to translate one programming language to another programming language?", phrased in various different ways). I responded to several of these questions by offering the Haxe programming language as a suggestion (since the Haxe programming language can be automatically trans-compiled to various languages). Today, I found out that these posts were deleted en masse by a moderator (probably mis-identified as spam, due to their similar content). Is there anything I can do to counteract this (perceived) problem?

---

Here is one example of one of my [Deleted posts (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244455/975097):

> There is a programming language called [Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457962/would-haxe-work-for-creating-libraries) that can be automatically translated to Java, C#, C++, Javascript, PHP, and several other languages. Haxe has the broadest trans-compilation support of any programming language that I've found so far, so it appears to be a good solution to this problem.

**Note that the link is *not to an external site*, but to another Stack Overflow post.**

Comment: Several of the answers that I posted linked to the same page (discussing how to create libraries in multiple programming languages by trans-compiling them from the Haxe programming language.) - this may have made the questions appear to be spam.

Comment: Flag question where your answer was deleted and ask moderators to recheck it again.

Comment: Also, if you can post links that would be great.

Comment: @jmort253 Here's one example of a relevant answer that was likely mistaken for spam: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244455/975097

Comment: It doesn't necessarily follow that it was a Moderator. It only takes a few spam flags from other users to auto-delete a post.

Comment: @AlEverett I saw the deleted questions - most of them were deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**After reviewing the example answer you provided, I'd have to say that it definitely has all of the markings of a typical spam post:**

- It was posted late. The question was asked June 2011, and you answered it a year and a half later.
- The answer includes something that sounds like a sales pitch, and includes a link to what appeared to be an external resource.

> Haxe has the broadest trans-compilation support of any programming language that I've found so far

- It was barely a small paragraph, with no code examples provided.

**Now, here is what makes this example seem less spammy:**

- You're not a brand new 1 rep user posting for the first time. Regulars can of course post spam, but typically, spam is posted by drive by users who never return.
- You've asked and answered a lot of questions, and they appear to mostly be legitimate posts.
- Most importantly, the link goes to another Stack Overflow post. Spam typically goes elsewhere. ;)

With that said, I haven't seen your other deleted answers, so I can't speak for all of them, but after taking a closer look, this one is clearly not spam. You could flag the post for moderator attention and explain that it isn't spam, and also point out that the link is to another Stack Overflow post. Use the "other" reason, so you can also ask for the mod to check other recently deleted posts.

Finally, please understand that there are currently 414 flags in the system right now, and moderators sometimes make mistakes, especially when on the surface something appears to be spam.

Comment: I noticed that this question was downvoted - why is it considered a bad question?

Comment: Your meta post? Don't worry about it. Downvotes just mean people disagree. Also, some may have downvoted because it's a duplicate and you may have been able to find the answer through search. However, you worded your question in a constructive manner to where you probably will get upvotes on it as well. One thing you might consider is editing and putting in your example deleted answers into the question for better context. Remember, only 10k users can see deleted posts, so to many, you may appear to be yet another complainer complaining about the big mean moderators. ;) Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but your evidence was buried in the comments. It's best to use comments to help improve the post, as not everyone will read comments, or read them carefully. I edited it for you to get the ball rolling. Good luck :)