# Can I answer all questions about my product or is it self-promotion?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

Does answering all questions about a product that I'm working on is considered self-promotion? I'm asking because of this part in FAQ:

> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

And is it necessary for me to disclose my affiliation?
Note that the questions are directly about how to use the product and I'm not suggesting my product as a solution

Comment: Yes thank you, That's exactly my question

Comment: see also: [How do I mention my own products in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15787/165773)

Answer (score 3):

It never hurts to disclose that you created a product. Not only is it a good practice, but it lends your answer extra credibility since it came from the product's creator.

A good example of this is the creator of f.lux [answering a feature request about their product](https://superuser.com/a/714525/358766).

Mentioning your own product shouldn't be an issue as long as it is relevant to the question, and you disclose your affiliation.